# Cobol error but cannot find it like I normally would find errors?

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I am working on a COBOL project and normally can find compile errors very easily within my program by looking through the error messages in the compile listing. But I just found one that I cannot seem to find all that easily.

This is how I select the job to see the locations of the errors:

```
  O Job#( )  Jobname  MaxRC  
  S J40195   myFile   000008 
    J30902   SSabdd33 000000 
    J50339   SSrrrr09 000000 
    J50325   SSeeeee0 000004
```

---

CC  *** CONDITION CODES DISPLAY ***
 LOG    JESMSGLG JES2
 JCL    JESJCL   JES2
 MSG    JESYSMSG JES2
 101    SYSPRINT TEST0001 ICEGENER
 104    SYSPRINT TEST0001 XPDTR
 105    PRTSORT  TEST0001 XPDTR
 107    SYSPRINT TEST0001 LKED
 108    CWPERRM  TEST0001 XPDTR    --> I would select this option to see the errors

---

Error Statements Here:

```
 PCSIO 054-S  INVALID ENTRY lENGTH.                                                                   
 PCSIO 324-S  TOTAL DUPLICATE VERSIONS OF THIS PROGRAM MAY EXCEED SHARED DIRECTORY BUFFER LIMIT        
 PCSIO 006-S  OUTPUT FILE CWPDDIO OPENMEM ERROR, RETURN CODE=48-410.
```

I am not sure what these error statements mean.

Comment: Those aren't COBOL error messages. They are error messages about creating a file for Xpediter, Compuware's debugger. Find yourself an Xpediter manual with error messages in.

Comment: Thank you. I have not been able to get past this. i have not used Xpediter for several weeks. I have not used this program in Xpediter. Every time I compile it gives me a return code of 8. How do I get past this little glich because the return code (for us anyway) is a 4 which signifies a good compile.

Comment: You should have something separate for compiling a program when you use Xpediter. I'd ask colleagues which option to select to compile without Xpediter.

Answer (score 0):

Not Off-topic, so you can have an answer.

If attempting to use Compuware's Expediter IBM Mainframe debugger product and you want to understand any of the messages, you need to find the Xpediter Messages and Codes manual at your installation and any local installation-specific documentation on how the product should be used at your site.

You should be able to register on www.compuware.com, for free, and have access to downloadable manuals, for free, but you will need to locate the license information at your site and check that there are not already internal procedures for obtaining the documentation.

When receiving error messages, consult the messages manual first. If this does not give a resolution, consult colleagues, the appropriate local support group, Compuware support (your site is paying for that, but ensure you follow local procedures for doing so, there may be a central contact point at your site for support requests to software suppliers), search the web.

Sometimes you will be able to circumvent that by searching the web early, or asking questions somewhere, but many times simply looking in the manual will be enough, and other times they will be site-specific issues, so better to go through everything in the approximate order above.

If you are not intending to use Xpediter for a program and you get the messages, it means that the "wrong" JCL is being used, which usually means that the wrong compile method has been selected from an ISPF panel. You need to find out, at your site, colleagues being the easiest way, how to compile a program without using Xpediter. This will be/can be entirely site-specific, so you have to find out how it is done at your site and you can get nothing but generalised answers here which will sometimes confuse, send you down a wrong route and waste your time, or otherwise not be other than tangentially helpful to you.